# apache v2.4 remove old v2.2 'Deny from env=BlockCountry' directive

Tags: apache, apache2.4, apache2.2

I protect my HTTP(s) vhosts with geoIP

```
<Directory /srv/www/vhosts>

    MaxMindDBEnable On
    MaxMindDBFile DB /usr/local/share/maxminddb/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb
    MaxMindDBEnv MM_COUNTRY_CODE DB/country/iso_code

    SetEnvIf MM_COUNTRY_CODE ^(RU|CN|HK|IN) BlockCountry
    Deny from env=BlockCountry

    Options  FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

1.) Am I correct that  I mix v2.2 `Deny from env=BlockCountry` and v2.4 `Require all granted` directives here.
If yes I searched the web to replace the `Deny from env=BlockCountry` with an apache2.4 alternative but cannot find one. How can I get rid of the old `Deny` directicve ?

2.) Am I correct that my GeoIP code in my apache2.conf works with this version inconsistent directives just by some "luck" , because I never set the order which rule ( Require or Deny ) comes first like I would do in v2.2 `apache order allow deny`

3.) `Require env BlockCountry` works but than all the blocked Countries have access and all the other not ( I test always with VPN )
So I tried `Require not env BlockCountry` but this leads to an error when I restart apache web server

Answer (score 0):

You could negate your rule.

Instead of
SetEnvIf MM_COUNTRY_CODE ^(RU|CN|HK|IN) BlockCountry
Deny from env=BlockCountry

set.
SetEnvIf MM_COUNTRY_CODE !^(RU|CN|HK|IN) AllowCountry
Require env AllowCountry